# IntelliJ SBT project cannot resolve SBT symbols

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I'm banging my head against the wall on this one.

Trying to open a cloned git SBT project at work. It is a combined Java and Scala Play project, with scala 2.11.1, SBT 0.13.6, and Play 2.5.

I use IntelliJ to import project from the cloned repo, with JDK 1.8, and all download and SBT checkboxes checked, and then run either SBT refresh, or reload from SBT shell.

After doing so, all SBT and Play code on both build.sbt and plugins.sbt is painted red, as in "cannot resolve symbol".

Looking at Intellij poroject structure, I have JDK1.8 on the SDK tab, and scala-sdk-2.11 on the Global Libraries tab. SBT and Scala plugins are installed and enabled.

SBT refresh fails on the following Play dependency, which could be the reason for the above symptom, since the SBT build does not complete:

> unresolved dependency:
>   com.typesafe.play.plugins#play-statsd_2.11;2.3.0: not found

The dependency does exist:
http://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/maven-releases/com/typesafe/play/plugins/play-statsd_2.11/2.3.0/

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Can you please share dependency for `Play StatsD`. Which version of `Play StatsD` has been used in build.sbt?

Comment: There is no such dependency in build.sbt

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem is on the typesafe side, not on my env.
All typesafe dependencies on the project are resolved as expected, except for play-statsd.

I manually added this dependency to my ivy cache, and now everything works fine.
It was a hard one to isolate, because apparently everybody here already have the dependency on their caches, so seems like their updates work well...

If anyone has the same problem, fetch the dependency from the [bintray repository](http://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/maven-releases/com/typesafe/play/plugins/play-statsd_2.11/2.3.0/), and manually add it to your ivy cache, e.g.

> ~/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play.plugins/play-statsd_2.11

The github play-plugins repository has been archived, so I can't open an issue, and don'y know if anyone will take care of it anyway.

Comment: It's possible the resolver isn't set up correctly, you can check by entering `resolvers` in the sbt shell, and looking at what repositories are being tried in the sbt log when updating

Answer (score 0):

Unresolved dependency error usually related with Scala version that you are using.

Here is Play 2.3.x documentation.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration22#Update-Scala-version

If you are able to use Play 2.7.x, your issue will be fixed.

Comment: Hi..It's problem with play-statsd jar not Play jar.

Comment: Thanks Bahadir, but I'm bound to Play 2.5, and migration documentation does not offer any remedy to my issue

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add `Play StatsD` dependency in build.sbt as below and check once.

`"com.typesafe.play.plugins" %% "play-statsd" % "2.3.0"`

Comment: Tried adding the dependency, and tried excluding it. None do the trick.

Comment: If you don't have `play statsd ` depedency in built.sbt file then from where it is trying to download? Can you please share all your dependencies.Not scree shot please.

Comment: Please share your full build.sbt content.

Comment: It's most likely some internal dependency in Play

Answer (score 0):

You should add maven-releases resolver:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe Resolver" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases/"
```